# Vertical and Horizontal compositions and endofunctors

Tags: category-theory

Consider natural transformations between endofunctors. Two types of compositions are possible for natural transformations: [vertical](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vertical+composition) and [horizontal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+composition). Can I say that they are the same (if the natural transformations are between endofunctors)?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you believe to be true? What equation do you think holds? What I think you may be suggesting leads to an equation between things that aren't even of the same "type". For example, if $\tau:T\to T$, then $\tau*\tau : T^2\to T^2$ while $\tau\circ\tau : T\to T$.

Comment: My question was about equality in all cases. Your example shows that my statement is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact not only will they not generally be the same, one can make sense when the other doesn't.

For example, in a category with binary products there's a twist natural transformation $\tau:(A\times -)\to (-\times A).$ Note that vertically composing this with itself doesn't even make sense (the domain and codomain are different), but horizontal composition is fine; $(\tau*\tau)_B$ is the map  $(a,(a',b))\mapsto ((b,a'),a)$.